# Opening a text file from command line argument?

Tags: c

I have two C files, one is the function definitions file titled "`function.c`" and the other is the main file titled "`main.c`". I am trying to open a text file that is entered by the user as a command-line argument, like below.

```
./program file.txt
```

The program then uses "file.txt". My `main.c` code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *readFile(char *filename);

int main(int arg_count, char *arg[]) {

  FILE *fptr = fopen(arg[1] ,"r");

  if(fptr == NULL) {
    printf("Error! opening file");
    exit(1);
  }
  readFile(arg[1]);

  return 0;
}
```

The main function calls the function within the other c file called "readFile," in "function.c," which is below:

```
char *readFile(char *filename) {

fgets(arg[1], sizeof(arg[1]), stdin);
```

> *rest of code*

```
  return 0;
}
```

What I want to do with the file, will be written inside of `function.c` (within the readFile function). When I tried compiling it, it gave me an error saying "error: ‘arg’ undeclared," but when I try to declare it, it gives me another error. Note that I compile both files together, along with a header file containing the function prototype. How do I make it so that what is entered from the command line, carries over into the `function.c` file, so I can use that file?

Comment: NB: You should not use `arg[1]` until you've verified it is not a null pointer by testing `arg_count > 1`. If the user didn't type a file name on the command line, it will be a null pointer (`arg[0]` is the program name, `arg_count` is 1, and `arg[arg_count]` is a null pointer). You should consider what to do if the user provides more than one filename on the command line. Often, you should iterate over all the files; sometimes, you should generate an error. Your nomenclature isn't wrong. However, it is more conventional to use `argc` for 'argument count' and `argv` for 'argument vector'.

Comment: regarding: `readFile(arg[1]);`  You already have a `file descriptor pointer from: `FILE *fptr = fopen(arg[1] ,"r");`  either use that pointer or remove all of:  `FILE *fptr = fopen(arg[1] ,"r");

  if(fptr == NULL) {
    printf("Error! opening file");
    exit(1);
  }`

Comment: the posted code fails to close the file, when done with it, via a call to `fclose()`

Comment: regarding: `fgets(arg[1], sizeof(arg[1]), stdin);`  this is trying to read from the keyboard (stdin) into a buffer `arg[1]`.   NOT what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments to a function only exist within the scope of that function. `char *arg[]` does not exist in the scope of the function `readFile`, even if both functions are in the same source file.

`readFile` gets a pointer to `arg[1]` in the argument called `filename`; use that instead in `readFile`.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code::

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly checks for errors (except for call to `fgets()`)
4. documents why each header file is included
5. properly verifies existence of expected command line parameter
6. makes use of dynamic memory for passing string back to caller
7. cleans up after itself (fclose() and free())
8. uses a 'include' guard to prevent multiple include of the header file
9. inserts any error messages into `stderr` to inform the user of any problems
10. uses a `#define` to give the 'magic' number (20) a meaningful name

and now, the proposed code:

```
// myHeader.h
#ifndef MY_HEADER_H
#define MY_HEADER_H

char *readFile(char *filename);   

#endif  // MY_HEADER_H


// main.c
#include <stdio.h>    // fprintf()
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, free()
#include "myHeader.h"


int main(int arg_count, char *arg[]) 
{
    if( arg_count <= 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s inputFileName\n", arg[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    // implied else, command line parameter was entered by user
        

    char *buffer = readFile(arg[1]);
    
    printf( "%s]n", buffer );
    
    free( buffer );

  return 0;
}


// function.c
#include <stdio.h>   // fopen(), fclose(), perror(), fgets()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, malloc()
#include "myHeader.h"

#define MAX_BUF_LEN 20

char *readFile( char *filename ) 
{
    FILE *fptr = fopen( filename , "r" );

    if( fptr == NULL ) 
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    //implied else, fopen successful
    
    // read first line from file
    char *buffer = malloc( MAX_BUF_LEN );
    if( buffer == NULL )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful
    
    fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), fptr );

    fclose( fptr );
    
    return buffer;
}
```